# Maximum height of a projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

How do I calculate the maximum height of a projectile that I throw straight up if all the information I have is the total time of the projectile in the air (which is 4 seconds) with an equation?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the projectile is under the influence of the acceleration of gravity only, then this can be easily done by understanding the nature of the motion of the projectile being symmetric "parabolic in motion", in other words the projectile would spent an equal time reaching the maximum altitude and equal time to get back to the same level from there. This means that the projectile would take 2 seconds to reach the highest vertical displacement and another 2 seconds to get back to the same level from which it was initially projected.

And knowing that the acceleration of gravity is equal to 9.81 $\rm{m}/\rm{s}^2$, we can use Newton's equation of motion in order to find its initial velocity by which it was projected, 
$$ v = u - at$$
Where the final velocity "the velocity at the maximum displacement" would be zero, substituting the knowns in the above equation we then solve for $ u $, then again using Newton's equation of motions to find the maximum displacement, where 
$$ s = ut - \dfrac{1}{2} ~ \!  a t^2$$
Keeping in mind, that we are going to substitute by the time to be equal to 2 seconds, because this would be the time instance at which the projectile would reach the maximum height.